# SQL Server Reporting Services Upgrade/Migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, ssrs

I couldn't find any documentation on this. I'm currently doing a dry run of SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2008 R2 upgrade/migration. I've backed everything up (encryption key and configuration files) and did a native backup then restore on the new server.

As it's restoring, I see "Converting database 'ReportServer' from version 611 to the current version 661.

Does this mean the server is doing all the heavy lifting of the upgrade in the background. After the restore, I am able to bring the service up and going rather quickly. Is this "upgrade" documented anywhere?

Comment: 661 is the version number for SQL Server 2008 R2, it is simply upgrading the database for that specific message.

Comment: Is it running a DDL script in the background? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: No, the conversion for a database from one version to a higher version is not documented by Microsoft.